# I need a specific rule to explain difference between 'were' and 'did' questions

Tags: past-tense, questions

A student has asked me to give him a very clear explanation of why we use two structures in the past tense to make questions:

Did (eg Did you see him yesterday?)
Were (were you with him yesterday?)

I find that when I try to explain I go round in circles and confuse him even more. He's pre-intermediate and needs a very simple explanation that he can grasp and my brain is fried from trying...any help would be gratefully received! Thanks :)

Comment: They are just past-tense forms of the verbs *do* and *be*.

Answer (score 8):

This is a matter of what linguists call *do-*support.

The inversion which we employ in yes/no questions like "Did you see him?" and *Were you with him?*<sup>†</sup> is *subject-auxiliary* inversion—that is, the subject inverts only with auxiliary ('helping') verbs: *have*, *be*, *do* and the modals *can/could*, *may/might*, *must*, *shall/should* and *will/would*.

If the declarative version of your sentence has an auxiliary, you invert it with the subject to make a question:

> <sub>SUBJ</sub>**You** <sub>AUX</sub>**have** seen him → <sub>AUX</sub>**Have** <sub>SUBJ</sub>**you** seen him?

But lexical ('main') verbs, like *see*, which can stand alone without an auxiliary, don't invert;<sup>‡</sup> so if the declarative version uses one of these verbs without an auxiliary, how do you make a question? —You bring *do* in to act as the auxiliary you need, and invert that with the subject:

> <sub>SUBJ</sub>**You** saw him → <sub>SUBJ</sub>**You** <sub>AUX</sub>**did** see him → <sub>AUX</sub>**Did** <sub>SUBJ</sub>**you** see him?

There's just one tricky thing here. *Have*, *do* and *be* can all act as either auxiliaries OR lexical verbs. When you use *do* by itself as a lexical verb, as in *do your homework*, it requires *do-*support for inversion in questions:

> **Did you** do your homework?

But *be* **always** acts as an auxiliary and inverts without *do-*support, even when it's the only verb in the clause:

> <sub>SUBJ</sub>**You** <sub>AUX</sub>**were** with him → <sub>AUX</sub>**Were** <sub>SUBJ</sub>**you** with him?

And lexical *have* is betwixt-and-between: in ordinary speech today it requires *do-*support in questions:

> **Do you** have any questions?

But for a long time lexical *have* could be used like an auxiliary, and there are still a few people who use it that way:

> **Have you** any questions?

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>and in negations like *I don't see him*—but we won't worry about that here.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>Once upon a time they did invert—*Saw you the field? Came you from Shrewsbury?*—but that use mostly disappeared some 400 years ago, with a couple of exceptions addressed later.</sub>

Comment: What an answer, perfect. BTW, Does "betwixt-and-between" mean "in ordinary speech today it requires do-support in questions"?

Comment: @Cardinal It doesn't **require** it--but almost everybody uses it. We'll probably have a few holdouts for another generation or so.

Comment: We'll have holdouts as long as I live and breath! ;-) Actually I might *say* either of them and I'm much more likely to say "do you have", but they can prise my right to accept both from my cold, dead hands.

Comment: One _could_ say "Saw you him?", but only if one Yoda is.

Comment: @MontyHarder Sounds more like Shakespeare. I would expect Yoda to say "See him, did you?"

Comment: I'm one of those holdouts, e.g. I'm more likely, despite being American, to begin a question with *Have you got…?* rather than *Do you have…?*, although my preferred form is much more common in BrE.

Comment: @Giambattista I'm of the *You got...?* school, but I don't take it as far as *Do you got...* yet :)

Comment: @StoneyB LOL To me, *You got…* is just an elided version of *Have you got…?* You just won't find many Americans that use *have* in that instance; but I'm sure that what it evolved from.

Answer (score 1):

For most verbs, the simple past tense when making questions is formed by beginning your sentence with *did*, then comes the subject, and finally the verb itself in present tense form. *to be* is just somewhat special in that regard. You simply put the verb (was or were) in front of the subject. That's really all there is to it at the end of the day.

Comment: *To be* is not at all *special in that regard*. The rule is that you cannot begin a question with an action verb. Questions can begin with any linking verb (e.g. have/have got, be, do, etc.) or modal verb (can, should would, etc.). When the only verb in the question is an action verb, a linking or modal verb must be inserted in front of the action verb.